# classe QWidget dentro de classe QMainWindow

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt-5, pyside

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QSpacerItem, QLabel, QComboBox
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QSizePolicy, QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QMetaObject
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap


class Janela(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.contentor = QWidget(self)
        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.contentor)
        self.menu = QHBoxLayout()
        self.adicionar = QPushButton(self.contentor)
        icone_adicionar = QIcon()
        icone_adicionar.addPixmap(QPixmap("adicionar.png"))
        self.adicionar.setIcon(icone_adicionar)
        self.adicionar.setFlat(True)
        self.menu.addWidget(self.adicionar)
        self.listar = QPushButton(self.contentor)
        icone_listar = QIcon()
        icone_listar.addPixmap(QPixmap("listar.png"))
        self.listar.setIcon(icone_listar)
        self.listar.setFlat(True)
        self.menu.addWidget(self.listar)
        self.configurar = QPushButton(self.contentor)
        icone_configurar = QIcon()
        icone_configurar.addPixmap(QPixmap("configurar.png"))
        self.configurar.setIcon(icone_configurar)
        self.configurar.setFlat(True)
        self.menu.addWidget(self.configurar)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.menu)
        # ---------------------------------------#
        self.conteudo = QWidget(self.contentor)
        # ---------------------------------------#
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.conteudo)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.contentor)
        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(self)


class Conteudo(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        spacer = QSpacerItem(20, 87,
                             QSizePolicy.Minimum,
                             QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.verticalLayout.addItem(spacer)
        self.login = QPushButton(self)
        icon = QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QPixmap("google.png"),
                       QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
        self.login.setIcon(icon)
        self.login.setText("Entrar com Google")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.login)
        self.horizontalLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.label_tema = QLabel(self)
        self.label_tema.setText("Tema")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_tema)
        self.tema = QComboBox(self)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.tema)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        self.verticalLayout.addItem(spacer)
        self.faz_bkp = QPushButton(self)
        self.faz_bkp.setText("Fazer backup")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.faz_bkp)
        self.imp_bkp = QPushButton(self)
        self.imp_bkp.setText("Importar backup")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.imp_bkp)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    aplicativo = QApplication(sys.argv)
    janela = Janela()
    janela.show()

    aplicativo.exec_()
```

A classe Janela apresenta apenas um QHBoxLayout - Janela()['menu'] - com botões que mudariam o conteudo de um QWidget - Janela()['conteudo']. Quando a variável 'janela' é setada tanto com a classe Janela  quanto com a Conteudo, funciona. No entanto ao tentar Janela()['conteudo'] = Conteudo dá erro. Como devo proceder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente isto:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QSpacerItem, QLabel, QComboBox
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QSizePolicy, QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore    import QMetaObject
from PyQt5.QtGui     import QIcon, QPixmap


class Janela(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.contentor = QWidget() 

        self.setCentralWidget(self.contentor)             # +

        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.contentor)

        self.menu = QHBoxLayout()
        self.adicionar  = QPushButton(self.contentor)
        icone_adicionar = QIcon()
        icone_adicionar.addPixmap(QPixmap("D:/_Qt/img/py-qt.png"))
        self.adicionar.setIcon(icone_adicionar)
        self.adicionar.setFlat(True)
        self.menu.addWidget(self.adicionar)
        self.listar = QPushButton(self.contentor)
        icone_listar = QIcon()
        icone_listar.addPixmap(QPixmap("D:/_Qt/img/1.png"))
        self.listar.setIcon(icone_listar)
        self.listar.setFlat(True)
        self.menu.addWidget(self.listar)
        self.configurar = QPushButton(self.contentor)
        icone_configurar = QIcon()
        icone_configurar.addPixmap(QPixmap("D:/_Qt/img/2.png"))
        self.configurar.setIcon(icone_configurar)
        self.configurar.setFlat(True)
        self.menu.addWidget(self.configurar)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.menu)

        # ---------------------------------------#
#        self.conteudo = QWidget(self.contentor)
        self.conteudo = Conteudo(self.contentor)         # +
        # ---------------------------------------#

        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.conteudo)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.contentor)
        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(self)


class Conteudo(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):                      # + parent=None
        super().__init__(parent)                          # + parent

        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        spacer = QSpacerItem(20, 87,
                             QSizePolicy.Minimum,
                             QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.verticalLayout.addItem(spacer)
        self.login = QPushButton(self)
        icon = QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QPixmap("D:/_Qt/img/cat.png"),
                       QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
        self.login.setIcon(icon)
        self.login.setText("Entrar com Google")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.login)
        self.horizontalLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.label_tema = QLabel(self)
        self.label_tema.setText("Tema")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_tema)
        self.tema = QComboBox(self)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.tema)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        self.verticalLayout.addItem(spacer)
        self.faz_bkp = QPushButton(self)
        self.faz_bkp.setText("Fazer backup")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.faz_bkp)
        self.imp_bkp = QPushButton(self)
        self.imp_bkp.setText("Importar backup")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.imp_bkp)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    aplicativo = QApplication(sys.argv)
    janela = Janela()
    janela.show()
    aplicativo.exec_()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]